# Vim's PHP syntax highlighting ignores non-scripty PHP files

Tags: php, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

When editing PHP files that are part of a framework, there's no `<?php` tag in the beginning of the file.  Thus, Vim doesn't recognize the PHP in that file as PHP.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: how it could be no `<?php` if it's php file, do you use eval on it, or what?

Comment: @kmlnvm there is no requirement for a PHP file to start with, or in fact include ANY PHP at all.

Comment: @Greg did you try https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic ?

Comment: Syntastic is a syntax checker, yes?  This is syntactically correct PHP in need of proper syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Run `:set filetype=php` to manually tell Vim that the current file is a PHP file.

Comment: Not the problem.  It already thinks filetype is php.  It's that the syntax highlighter thinks there needs to be a <?php first.